# Input file определённого типа НЕ MIME-тип

Tags: javascript, html, файлы, input

Стоит задача подгрузить файл средствами HTML и JS. Код

```
<input type="file" class="file-for-import" />
```

Появляется стандартная форма загрузки файла. Мне нужно, чтобы подгружался только определённый тип файлов, например, shp. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type='file' accept='.shp,.csv'>
```

Comment: Работает не совсем так, как нужно. Мне нужны несколько расширений: к примеру, .shp и .csv. И когда я в атрибуте `accept` указываю только один из этих типов, оно работает, но когда указываю оба, вместо перечня расширений в окне загрузки написано "Пользовательские типы". Как мне сделать видимым для пользователя список допустимых расширений?

Comment: @NewDevelop, тут только mime или через запятую. Как вариант, можно указать рядом с input разрешённые типы

Comment: `<input type="file" class="file-for-import" accept=".csv,.shp" />` с таким кодом я не вижу расширений в пользовательской форме.

Comment: @NewDevelop, да, но фильтр применяется. Если создать в пустой папке файлы `1.csv`, `2.shp` и `3.txt`, при выборе в окне отобразятся только первые два

Comment: @NewDevelop, даже при указании нескольких mime типов, отображается "Другие файлы", ибо не влезет в одну строку несколько обозначений. Тоже самое и с file type